# How to make Gallery CSS slider from GitHub responsive

Tags: html, css, github, slider

I found this pure CSS slider on GitHub that I want to use but it's not responsive and I need it to be. I've tried changing `.gallery .item` to `width:100%` but for some reason the height needs to be set in pixels because `%` doesn't seem to work and if I don't define a height the slides are not quite visible.

Here's the demo: http://wap9.info/6334

Source GitHub: http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/

As you can see if you reduce your browser's size, the slider height stays the same. Can I make this responsive?

Answer (score 0):

It already is responsive. When I change my browser height and width then the hero/slider changes accordingly and nothing seems to break.

EDIT::
Try to remove the `js-autoheight` hook class from the hero section.

```
<section style="min-height: /*some value*/px;" class="js-autoheight gallery items-/*Some value*/">
```

Comment: I edited my question with: "if you reduce your browser's size, the slider height stays the same. Can I make it responsive?" Try it with the 3rd slide and see how this affects the image.  I will be using image backgrounds too and would like them to be fully visible at all screen size. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, so you mean you don't want the background image to get cut off? I think I'm misunderstanding you. If I reduce the browser's size the slider height changes. http://i.imgur.com/Ert5hYd.gif

Comment: Correct, I don't want the background image to get cut off. If you reduce the browser's size horizontally from right to left, I would like the height to resize proportionally like most responsive sliders do. i.e http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: @user1724434 Check my new answer and tell me if it solves your problem.

Comment: Oddly enough, the actual downloaded files from GitHub don't have that hook.  I uploaded the actual slider files so you can see: http://wap9.info/6334

Comment: @user1724434 That's strange. When I looked at the `gh-pages` branch of the repository, that class seems to be included in the hero section. I've made a suggestion to the repository to show you where it is. https://github.com/benschwarz/gallery-css/compare/gh-pages...OmriN7:patch-1

Comment: I see that, thanks. Anyhow, it doesn't seem to make a difference whether the "js-autoheight" div is there or not. The height is still not responsive.

Comment: @user1724434 I saw it inside the `gh-branch` of the repository you posted in the original question (http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/)

Here's the file: https://github.com/benschwarz/gallery-css/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Here's the fix: https://github.com/benschwarz/gallery-css/compare/gh-pages...OmriN7:patch-1

Comment: I added the class but the height is still not responsive: wap9.info/6334